# Define a norm on $\mathbb{R}^3$ such that unit vectors have norm $1$ while $\|(1,1,1)\|<\frac{1}{100}$

Tags: linear-algebra, normed-spaces

> **Problem.** Describe a norm $\lVert\cdot\rVert_0$ on $\mathbb{R}^3$ such that the standard unit vectors have norm $1$ while $\lVert(1,1,1)\rVert_0<\frac{1}{100}$.

This norm looks not so trivial because of the restriction $\lVert(1,1,1)\rVert_0<\frac{1}{100}$.

$p$-norms do not work at all. Even though $\lVert(1,1,1)\rVert_p$ decreases as $p\to\infty$, we still only have $\lVert(1,1,1)\rVert_\infty=1\gg 1/100$.

Hope anyone have good ideas.

Comment: Hint: Think of a prolate spheroid containing the standard unit vectors that is Very Long in the direction $(1, 1, 1)$, and make that your unit sphere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first approach I thought of was as follows: for any positive definite matrix $A$, the function $\|x\|_A = \sqrt{x^TAx}$ defines a norm, and the diagonal entries of $A$ are the norms of the standard unit vectors.

With that in mind, consider the matrix
$$
A = \pmatrix{1 & \epsilon - 1/2& \epsilon - 1/2\\\epsilon - 1/2 & 1 & \epsilon - 1/2 \\ \epsilon - 1/2 & \epsilon - 1/2 & 1},
$$
where $0 < \epsilon < 1/2$. The corresponding norm satisfies
$$
\|x\|_A^2 = \sum_{i=1}^3 x_i^2 - \sum_{1 \leq i<j \leq 3} (1 - 2 \epsilon) x_ix_j.
$$
We find that the standard unit vectors have norm $1$ for all such $\epsilon$. However, for sufficiently small $\epsilon$, we find that $\|(1,1,1)\|_A = \sqrt{6\cdot \epsilon} < 1/100.$

Comment: I didn't see Andrew's comment until posting this answer, but for what it's worth the surface $\|x\|_A = 1$ is the spheroid being referred to in the comment

Comment: (+1) Elegantly put. :)